# Laravel Carbon date diffInDays() on string error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I need to find the difference between the two dates.  Say i have 2017-02-01 - 2017-01-01.  The number of days between the two days is the output

```
$formatted_dt1=Carbon::parse($a->date)->format('Y-m-d');
$formatted_dt2=Carbon::parse($c->dt)->format('Y-m-d');
$date_diff=$formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2);
```

If I give the above code I get the error as

```
FatalThrowableError in ReportsController.php line 67:
Call to a member function diffInDays() on string
```

Comment: While all those answers are correct, you should specify date and dt to be dates in the corresponding model - see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators for more information

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Carbon `format()` function will convert to string so remove `format('Y-m-d')` like this:

```
$formatted_dt1=Carbon::parse($a->date);

$formatted_dt2=Carbon::parse($c->dt);

$date_diff=$formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2);
```

Hope you understand. You can see docs [here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but try this:

```
$formatted_dt1=Carbon::parse($a->date);
$formatted_dt2=Carbon::parse($c->dt);
$date_diff=$formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to `use Carbon\Carbon;`

- You can use `diffInDays` for **days**.
- You can use `diffInHours` for **Hours**.
- You can use `diffInMinutes` for **Minutes**.
- You can use `DiffInSeconds` for **Seconds**.

---

```
    $formatted_dt1=Carbon::parse('2019-09-26 00:00:00');
    $formatted_dt2=Carbon::parse('2019-09-28 00:00:00');


    $date_diff=$formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2);
    echo $date_diff.' Day '; //2 days


    $hours_diff = $formatted_dt1->diffInHours($formatted_dt2); 
    echo $date_diff.' Hours '; //48 Hours 


    $Minutesdiff = $formatted_dt1->diffInMinutes($formatted_dt2); 
    echo $Minutesdiff.' Minutes '; //2880 Minutes



    $seconddiff = $formatted_dt1->DiffInSeconds($formatted_dt2); 
    echo $seconddiff.' Seconds '; //172800  Seconds
    exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way,

```
$formatted_dt1=Carbon::parse($a->date);
$formatted_dt2=Carbon::parse($c->dt);
$date_diff=$formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2)->format('Y-m-d');
```

First get the difference from two dates and then format the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the `diffInDays()` function on a Carbon instance at before date format apply.

```
$formatted_dt1=Carbon::parse($a->date);
$formatted_dt2=Carbon::parse($c->dt);
```

Now you should be able to compare:

```
$date_diff=$formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2);
```

if you want to apply date format, try below for compare them:

```
$date_diff=$formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Check this [document](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are having this problem because you stored your date as string in the database. You can perform `diffInDays($updated_at)` or `diffInDays($created_at)` on the original laravel's `created_at` and `updated_at` because Laravel already stores them as dates by default so, when you are fetching them from the database, laravel gives it to you as a carborn instance (try `dd($created_at)`).

To solve your problem, go to your model and use this to convert your date column to dates

```
protected $dates = [
'my_date',
'my_other_date'
]
```

Then, you can now do

```
$formatted_dt1=Carbon::parse($a->date)->format('Y-m-d');
$formatted_dt2=Carbon::parse($c->dt)->format('Y-m-d');
$date_diff=$formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2);
```

OR You can use

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($formatted_dt1)->diffInDays()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove format() carbon  format() it will convert string, so remove it,it will works,

```
$formatted_dt1=Carbon::parse($a->date);
$formatted_dt2=Carbon::parse($c->dt);
$date_diff=$formatted_dt1->diffInDays($formatted_dt2);
```